# Formula for continuously dividing by 2

Tags: calculus, limits, divisibility, physics

I was helping my daughter with her physics homework. The problem had a bee flying back and forth between two bikes moving toward each other.

The question was to see how far the bee traveled. Turned out that the first trip was 15km. The second was 7.5km. The third was 3.75km and the fourth was 1.875. (We estimated that the final answer was 30km)

I realized that each trip was half as far as the last one. But the total was not possible to calculate because there would technically be infinite trips.

As I tried to think of a way to express this mathematically, it reminded me of my long ago calculus classes. (I don’t use calculus in my day job, so I have mostly forgotten it.)

I am done with what my daughter needs to show for her problem, but I am curious:

How do you express and solve dividing a number by two and then repeatedly taking the quotient and dividing by two, getting the sum of all those numbers?

For example:

```
 15 + 15/2 + 7.5/2 + 3.75/2 + 1.875/2 + ...... + 15/2^(n-1)=30
```

Comment: If the first trip is $15$ km, the $n$th trip is $\displaystyle\frac{15}{2^{n-1}}$ km.

Comment: What is the original problem btw? Because I have seen a similar problem that can be done with a simple trick.

Comment: As for "*the total was not possible to calculate because there would technically be infinite trips*"  Says who?  Says [Zeno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes)?  People hardly took Zeno seriously two thousand years ago, much less so today.  You would do well to learn about [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).

Comment: @JMoravitz- Given enough paper/ram I feel you can divide by two for a VERY long time and still be able to divide by two again. That is what I meant.

Comment: There is a faster way of computing the answer, namely you figure out how long it takes the bicycles to meet, and then multiply that time by the speed of the bike.  Apparently von Neumann was given this problem at a dinner party, and he gave the answer immediately.  The host explained that many people solved it using infinite series.  To which von Neumann replied, is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to recognize is that repeatedly dividing by 2 is the same as repeatedly multiplying by 1/2. This seemingly irrelevant change is important because you'll find more information about repeated multiplication, simply because we prefer to talk about multiplication instead of division when possible.

Finding the sum of repeated multiplications is known as finding the sum of a geometric series; the values you computed are known as its *terms*. The sum of finitely many terms (starting from the first and adding each of them until some number of them have been included) is known as a *partial sum*. We can even talk about the *sum* of the whole series, which is the limit of the partial sums viewed as a sequence.

This should provide some search terms if you want to know more, but here's what you'd be likely to find in, say, a high school algebra class: a formula for any partial sum and a formula for the sum. Call the first term $a$ (for your problem, $15$) and let $r$ be such that the second term is $ar$ (i.e., let $r$ be the ratio between terms; and for your problem, $1/2$). Assuming $r \ne 1$, then the partial sum of the first $n$ terms is $a\left(\dfrac{1-r^n}{1-r}\right)$. If and only if $|r| < 1$, then the sum exists and is $\dfrac{a}{1-r}$.

Comment: Downvoted because I think the explanation is a bit clumsy and overcomplicated

Comment: Thank you!  That explains it quite nicely!  I am sure I learned this when I was in school.  But I could not recall enough to google it up.  Turns out our estimate of 30 was spot on.  (Either way, she (my daughter) was not expected to know this level of math. But I am sure she will get there some day so I really appreciate the refresher.)